# Green's function, stuck on this particular equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How does one find the Green's function for a differential equation in two variables which looks like,
$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} P -\omega P = j$
where $\omega$ is a $2\times 2 $matrix with $x-$dependent functions as elements,
$P$ is a one dimensional vector of the form $(P_1,P_2)$,
$j$ is also a one dimensional vector containing spatial$(x)$ derivatives of $P$.
I need to find  a Green's function that relates the value of $P$ at a certain position and time to a later time and different position.